# GRUB failed to install during boot-repair

Tags: 12.04

I get ^ that error after doing the steps told by Boot-Repair (after installing Ubuntu, I never got the option to boot it - it only let me "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu").

What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons, can review which may apply.
Locked BIOS or security (may be called Boot sector virus protection)  in BIOS prevents writing to MBR.
Similarly for UEFI, some have a defective efi partition that will not write to.

Also if you have RAID or Intel SRT, or created partitions with Windows and converted to dynamic partitions which do not work with Linux or you installed Windows in MBR mode to a drive that was previously gpt and you have left over gpt meta-data.